# What is the difference beetwen $ echo Hello world > file and $ echo Hello > file world in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, console, command

```
$ echo Hello world > file
$ echo Hello > file world
$ echo > file Hello world
$ > file echo Hello world
```

They all do the same thing, but I do not know why.

Comment: redirection (`>`) can technically occur anywhere on the command line. while the first option is "traditional", the others all do the same thing, because they redirect to file (`> file`), then execute whatever's left of the command line.

Comment: I wish Marc's comment was an answer so I could up vote it

Comment: Please, fix the title, as both versions are the same!

Answer (score 5):

From `man bash`:

> ```
>    Simple Commands
>        A  simple  command  is a sequence of optional variable assignments fol-
>        lowed by blank-separated words and redirections, and  terminated  by  a
>        control operator.  The first word specifies the command to be executed,
>        and is passed as argument zero.  The  remaining  words  are  passed  as
>        arguments to the invoked command.
> ```

That is, it doesn't specify the ordering of the "words and redirections".
Later in the REDIRECTIONS section:

> ```
> REDIRECTION
>        [...]
>        The [...] redirection  opera-
>        tors may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may fol-
>        low a command.  Redirections are processed in the  order  they  appear,
>        from left to right.
>        [...]
> ```

So they can appear anywhere.

And as you yourself have observed too, there's no difference between them in terms of the result.
There is a difference however in readability.

This is the most intuitive way of writing it:

```
echo Hello world > file
```

Really easy to understand. The `>` looks like an arrow, doesn't it.

The others are not so intuitive, less readable.
I suggest to stick to the first writing style.